# Finding standard deviations along x and y in 2D numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, standard-deviation

If I have a 2D numpy array composed of points (x, y) that give some value z(x, y) at each point, can I find the standard deviation along the x-axis and along the y-axis? I know that `np.std(data)` will simply find the standard deviation of the entire dataset, but that's not want I want. Also, adding in `axis=0` or `axis=1` computes the standard deviations along each axis for as many rows or columns that you have. If I just want one standard deviation along the y-axis, and another along the x-axis, can I find these in a dataset like this? From my understanding, standard deviations along x and y normally make sense when you have points x with values y(x). But I need some `sigma_x` and `sigma_y` for a 2D Gaussian fit I'm trying to do. Is this possible?

Here is an oversimplified example, since my actual data is much larger.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[1, 5, 0, 3], [3, 5, 1, 1], [41, 33, 9, 20], [11, 20, 4, 13]])

print(np.std(data)) #not what I want
>>> 11.78386 

print(np.std(data, axis=0)) #this gives me as many results as there are rows/columns so it's not what I want
>>> [16.03 11.69 3.5 7.69]
```

I'm not sure how the output corresponding to what I want would look like, since I'm not even sure if it's possible in a 2D array with shape > nx2. But I want to know if it's possible to compute a standard deviation along the x-axis, and one along the y-axis. I'm not even sure if this makes sense for a 2D array... But if it doesn't, I'm not sure what to input as my `sigma_x` and `sigma_y` for a 2D Gaussian fit.

Comment: That's just a solid block of text. Please consider breaking it down into paragraphs and a clear message of what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @roganjosh see edit

Comment: I'm not at all clear what you mean by "a standard deviation along the x-axis".   Which array values does that include?  It's a simple matter of selecting the values and applying the `std` operation, no?

Comment: The only obvious meaning for "a standard deviation along the x axis" is "the standard deviations for every column", which is exactly what you say you _don't_ want. So, what _do_ you want? Maybe you have some intended rule to get the distance between two rows as a single float, and you want the standard deviation using that distance rule? If so, you need to tell us what that rule is, and we can show you how to implement it.

Comment: I think what I'll need to do is get the standard deviations along x and y at the row or column where my peak lies. I think that's where the examples I was reading were lacking in explaining... in this case if I have (x0, y0) coordinates for my peak I could probably do `np.std(data, axis=0)[x0]` and `np.std(data, axis=1)[y0]`. But I'm not positive if this would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Standard deviation doesn't care whether `y = f(x)` or `(x, y)` are coordinates. It just measures how spread a set of values are. If you have `n` points `(x, y)` which make up a `nX2` size array, then the `std(axis=0)` is what you want. It creates a `(2, )`shaped array, where the first elements is the x-axis std, and the second the y-axis std. Whether that is useful, depends on what you want, and it ignores the correlation between `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thanks -- although my data sets are 2D arrays, they do not have shape nx2. I'm dealing with data sets of different shapes, but let's say for example I'm operating on a 600x600 array called `data`. Would this method still work in this case? I thought this would give me 600 results?

Comment: Usually, datasets shape is `num_patterns X num_features`, so you want the standard deviation along axis=0. On the other hand, if you have `2Xn` shape, you want `std(axis=1)`. In any case, you want the standard deviation of *the same* feature along *all different patterns*

Comment: Hmm, I see. In the simplified example I just added to my question, if I do `np.std` along `axis=0` I get four results of course. I get that there's one standard deviation along each pattern, but would it possible to reduce this to just one standard deviation in the `x` direction and another in `y`?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to separate the x axis in small intervals and compute the standard deviation of the y coordinates of the points within those intervals.
You could compute std(y_i), where y_i are the y coordinates for points x in the interval (x_min+i*delta_x, x_min+(i+1)*delta_x), choosing a small delta_x, such that enough points (x_j, y_j) lie within the interval.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0, 0.11, 0.1, 0.01, 0.2, 0.22, 0.23])
y = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2.1, 2.2])
num_intervals = 3
#sort the arrays
sort_inds = np.argsort(x)
x = x[sort_inds]
y = y[sort_inds]
# create intervals
x_range = x.max() - x.min()
x_intervals = np.linspace(np.min(x)+x_range/num_intervals, x.max()-x_range/num_intervals, num_intervals)
print(x_intervals)
>> [0.07666667 0.115      0.15333333]
```

Next, we split the arrays y and x using these intervals:

```
# get indices of x where the elements of x_intervals 
# should be inserted, in order to maintain the order  
# for sufficiently large num_intervals it 
# approximates the closest value in x to an element 
# in x_intervals
split_indices = np.unique(np.searchsorted(x, x_intervals, side='left')) 
ls_of_arrays_x = np.array_split(x, split_indices)
ls_of_arrays_y = np.array_split(y, split_indices)
print(ls_of_arrays_x)
print(ls_of_arrays_y)
>> [array([0.  , 0.01]), array([0.1 , 0.11]), array([0.2 , 0.22, 0.23])]
>> [array([1., 2.]), array([3., 2.]), array([2. , 2.1, 2.2])]
```

Now compute the x coordinates and the corresponding y std:

```
y_stds = np.array([np.std(yi) for yi in ls_of_arrays_y])
x_mean = np.array([np.std(xi) for xi in ls_of_arrays_x])
print(x_mean)
print(y_stds)
>> [0.005      0.105      0.21666667]
>> [0.5        0.5        0.08164966]
```

I hope it was what you were looking for.